# Deserializing an object graph from MSMQ that was enqueued using WCF and NetMsmqBinding

Tags: wcf, serialization, msmq

I've done some work using MSMQ with WCF and the NetMsmqBinding to generate messages and dequeue them as they arrive.  I've also standardized my solution by using an object graph as the message body.  This object contains meta data and an internal payload.

I'd like to construct an admin tool that can monitor queues and peek at the contents of messages.  So far I've been unsuccessful figuring out how to deserialize the Message.Body back into the object graph using the System.Messaging libraries.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any error messages? Also, have you seen Queue Explorer? http://www.cogin.com/mq/

Comment: By default, simply accessing the message.Body as an Object, you get the typical InvalidOperationException "Cannot find a formatter capable of reading this message".  Using an XmlMessageFormatter, it blows up because the contents are not valid XML.  Using a BinaryFormatter, it also fails with "Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument. Cannot recognize the serialization format."  I've just started trying to use a new method, but still having no luck.

Comment: You likely won't be able to. The NetMsmqBinding does not simply serialize your object graph to a message and enqueue the message. The message body has some protocol bits tacked on the front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any scope changing the WCF service bindings?

If you use MsmqIntegrationBinding rather than netMsmqBinding you have a range of formatter options you can specify in your binding. For example

```
<service name="MyQueueListenner">

    <!-- Active X endpoint -->
    <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\myQueue"
              binding="msmqIntegrationBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="ActiveXBinding"
              contract="MyContract" />

    <!-- .Net endpoint-->
    <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\myOtherQueue"
              binding="msmqIntegrationBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="DotNetBinding"
              contract="MyContract" />

  </service>
  ...

  <msmqIntegrationBinding>
    <binding serializationFormat="ActiveX" name="ActiveXBinding" durable="false" exactlyOnce="false">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding serializationFormat="Xml" name="DotNetBinding" durable="false" exactlyOnce="false">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </msmqIntegrationBinding>
```

This allows you the full range of formatters providing the greatest range of interoperability with your System.Messaging based sniffer.

The full list of values is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.msmqintegration.msmqmessageserializationformat.aspx

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer for 2 reasons.  1) it's the only one that has been offered and 2) it got me on the right track.  I suspect there may be something out there that can read and deserialize objects while still using NetMsmqBinding, but it would need to deserialize the underlying soap envelope in the message and resolve the namespace conflicts, contract params, etc.  I tried doing that but it was pretty messy.  Using MsmqIntegrationBinding is much cleaner on the sniffer side of things, but in my messaging infrastructure I had to use MsmqMessage<T> for all contract methods.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is old, but to serialize and back any object you can do the following:

//Sample

```
enter code here

public person class
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}

 public static person Desserialize(byte[] data)
        {
            person result = new person ();
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(m))
                {
                    result.id = reader.ReadInt32();
                    result.Name = reader.ReadString();

                }
            }
            return result;
        }



public byte[] Serialize()
        {
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m))
                {
                    writer.Write(id);
                    writer.Write(Name);

                }
                return m.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

// You can do
Byte[] w_byte = Person.serialize();

Person _Person = Person.Desiserile(w_byte);
}